# mac os x 10.9 - brew server requires sinatra error

Tags: ruby, macos, sinatra, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I want to run `brew server` on my Mac OS X Mavericks, but it throws an error:

```
MacBook-Pro-Dmitri:bin dmitri$ brew server
Error: Sinatra required but not found
To install: /usr/bin/gem install sinatra
```

The problem is that Sinatra is already installed:

```
MacBook-Pro-Dmitri:gems dmitri$ ls -a
. CFPropertyList-2.2.4 mini_portile-0.5.2 rack-1.5.2 rubygems-update-2.1.11 sqlite3-1.3.8
.. libxml-ruby-2.7.0 nokogiri-1.6.0 rack-protection-1.5.1 sinatra-1.4.4 tilt-1.4.1
```

Then I found that I have two Ruby versions on my machine:

```
MacBook-Pro-Dmitri:~ dmitri$ cd /Library/Ruby/Gems/
MacBook-Pro-Dmitri:Gems dmitri$ ls -a
.   ..  1.8 2.0.0
```

And Sinatra is in `2.0.0` folder.. Do I need to switch Ruby versions? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/gem install sinatra
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RVM, you might consider this procedure.

First, make sure you're using system Ruby, not one of the versions managed by RVM.

```
$ rvm use system
```

Verify that system Ruby is the one that you're using

```
$ rvm current
```

Check to see whether Sinatra is already installed.

```
$ gem list sinatra
```

If Sinatra is already installed with the system gems, then this solution might not work for you. Consider a different approach. However, if Sinatra is *not* installed, go ahead and install it like so...

```
$ sudo gem install sinatra
```

And then test the Homebrew web server.

```
$ brew server
```

Navigate your browser to `http://localhost:4567` and you should be able to review the list of Homebrew-installed packages from there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have RVM or another Ruby version control system? https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: no, 'cause I'm not a Ruby developer, there was no need in it before :)

Comment: I just think that it's a problem of Homebrew then.. why I need to handle versions..

Answer (score 0):

I realise I might be a bit late, but to anyone else experiencing the same issue: yes, you do need to install it for the system Ruby. Instead of

```
gem install sinatra
```

do

```
/usr/bin/gem install sinatra
```

You should be able to run brew server after that.